# Dirac delta forcing of a harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Is it possible to solve this differential equation:
$$\ddot{x}(t)+\omega^2x(t)=k\delta(t)$$
where $k$ is a constant and $\delta(t)$ the Dirac delta function?
Is it possible alternatively, to know something about the spectrum $X(\omega)$ of $x(t)$ without solving the equation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the equation using the Laplace transform. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%5Bt%5D%20%2b%20w%5E2%20x%5Bt%5D%20=%20k%20delta%5Bt%5D) has the details

Answer (score 1):

If for t<0 the oscillator is at rest, x=dx/dt=0, then the effect of this delta force is providing an initial velocity at t=0. By integrating the equation over an infinitesimal interval [-dt,dt] we find that at time t=dt the velocity is dx/dt=k and the displacement is still x=0. So these are the initial conditions at t=0, and the solution is x=(k/omega)*sin(omega*t) for t>0; x=0 for t<0.